# Storing & sign inside $_GET Variable

Tags: php, web

My Web application have 1 Index page Which is used to be an entry point for all another pages.

Every page url will look like that:

```
index.php?page=blabla.php
```

I ran into a problem when I needed to load a page that receiving multiple GET variables for example:

```
index.php?page=blabla.php?id=something&anotherid=anothersomething
```

Becuse page variable is storing inside `$_GET`.
`$_GET` automatically cut everything after `&` sign ..

There is any way to force get to store `&` sign ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It needs to be encoded as `%26`. In PHP `urlencode()` will do this. In JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` will do it.

Comment: i tried it , Its too late to encode in javascript, need to do the action while setting $_GET variable, I tried it but its not working.

Comment: It's too late once the request is sent. There's no way for PHP to know which `&` are separating different parameters and which are literal.

Comment: It needs to be fixed in the code that sends the request.

Comment: Also the `=` should be encoded as `%3D`

Comment: echo '<a href=index.php?page=quotehotel.php?id='.$id.'&quotekit='.$currentQuoteKit.' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm little-bit-margin float-right">Edit</a>';

This code echoing the link based on the id received from sql, any Idea how I should fix it?

Comment: Please put that in the question with code formatting.

Comment: If I'm not missing some additional processing that's happening, it should be a simple matter of changing that second `?` to a `&` as well: `index.php?page=blabla.php&id=something&anotherid=anothersomething`

Comment: Hi , 
The get variable "something" and  "anothersomething" should sent to another page (not blabla) , this is why your solution will not work.. I fixed it by changin & to %26 to manipulate $_GET variable that cutting the string after & by default

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `urlencode()` to ensure all the special characters in the query parameter are encoded.

```
echo '<a href=index.php?page=quotehotel.php?id=' . urlencode($id) . '&quotekit=' . urlencode($currentQuoteKit) . ' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm little-bit-margin float-right">Edit</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers,

Barmar Solution Worked for me:

```
<a href=index.php?page=quotehotel.php?quoteid='.$id.'%26quotekit='.$currentQuoteKit.' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm little-bit-margin float-right">Edit</a>
```